# What time zone is used for JPL tests?

Tags: time, jpl

The [JPL ASPIRE test video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcAgnQ9K7UY&feature=youtu.be) has a time code for the launch.

[image: Launch timestamp 250:13:30:13.066]

Day Of Year:Hour:Minute:Second.Microsecond.

What's the time zone?

Comment: Isn't the Julian date associated with UTC?

Comment: 250 is the day-of-year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UTC

This [page](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/aspire-parachute-test-a-success) gives launch local time as

> Friday, September 7, at 9:30 a.m

in Virginia, USA.

Virginia is Eastern Time (GMT-5) and September is in [Daylight Savings Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/virginia?year=2018) which accounts for the effective 4 hour difference.

Comment: Worth noting that giving time in UTC, or "zulu time", is an international standard for aviation in general. Since sending things through the air is a necessary part of sending them into space, no doubt JPL feels obliged to adhere to this standard.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's UTC.  This is based on [this page](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/third-aspire-test-confirms-mars-2020-parachute-a-go) which says

> In the early hours of Sept. 7, NASA broke a world record.

Well, 'the early hours' in a US timezone translates to mid day in UTC, and I can't see why, if they're not using local time, they'd use some timezone close-to-but-not UTC, so I therefore think it must be UTC.